# How do i calculate the encrypted password value of Access-Request RADIUS packet

Tags: python, md5, xor, freeradius

I am struggling with getting back the password plaintext I used in the FreeRadius setup

Following attributes are what I have got from my pcap file:

```
Plaintext password = "cisco123"
sharedkey = "sharedsecret"
Ciphertext password = "6ed3a35440abe69b2e8698109b809932" <-- plaintext password is cisco123
authenticator = "344c71c77a2b845b8856ffa968740b73"
```

So based on the research @http://www.untruth.org/~josh/security/radius/radius-auth.html the steps of deriving the encryped password under Section 2.1 is performed below to my understanding:

Concatenate the sharedkey and authenticator and store in a variable:

```
SharedKey + Authenticator:  sharedsecret344c71c77a2b845b8856ffa968740b73
```

MD5 hash the concatenated values :

```
Md5(SharedKey+Authenticator):  46608024c8f48fd0977bb944ae0eb89a
```

XOR the plaintext password with the MD5 concatentation result and the result should match the ciphertext

```
cisco12300000000 XOR 46608024c8f48fd0977bb944ae0eb89a
```

See below for my debugging results from my code (note my c1 is suppose to match Captured Ciphertext but it isnt ):

```
Shared Key:  sharedsecret
Authenticator:  344c71c77a2b845b8856ffa968740b73
SharedKey + Authenticator:  sharedsecret344c71c77a2b845b8856ffa968740b73
Md5(SharedKey+Authenticator):  46608024c8f48fd0977bb944ae0eb89a
p1(ascii):  cisco123
p1(hex):  636973636f3132330000000000000000
b1:  46608024c8f48fd0977bb944ae0eb89a
c1(p1 XOR b1):  2509f347a7c5bde3977bb944ae0eb89a
Captured Ciphertext  6ed3a35440abe69b2e8698109b809932
```

Can I clarify if my step was wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

Radius password was encrypted with Auth-Type.
It depends on your Auth-Type. If it was set to CHAP, password was encrypted with CHAP method. For me,I can not decrypted it.

You may need to set Auth-Type as PAP for plaintext password.